# SwiftUI how do I show the decimal point in a Text view with a number formatter?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a custom number pad view that writes the number to a string. I then want to display this string in a `Text` view using the `.number` format:

```
struct AddTransaction: View {

    private enum Constants {
        static let amountFont = Font.title
        static let amountFontWeight = Font.Weight.semibold
        static let padding: CGFloat = 42.0
    }

    // MARK: - Properties


    @State private var amountString = "0"

    // MARK: - Views

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text(Double(amountString) ?? 0.0, format: .number)
                    .font(Constants.amountFont)
                    .fontWeight(Constants.amountFontWeight)

                Spacer()

                NumberPad(numberString: $amountString)
                    .padding(.horizontal, Constants.padding)

            }
            .navigationTitle("Add Transaction")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }

}
```

The reason I am using the `.number` format is so I get the commas included in large numbers. e.g. `100,000`. However if I type "10." it will not show the decimal point until I type the next digit.

How do I get this decimal point to show as soon as it is tapped?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create your own formatter to achieve this like :

```
  static let numberFormat: NumberFormatter =  {
       let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
       return numberFormatter
   }()
```

And in body :

```
 Text(ContentView.numberFormat.number(from: amountString)!.doubleValue as NSNumber , formatter: ContentView.numberFormat)
```

Comment: This always show the decimal point now and always has two leading 0s. I want the decimal to only appear when tapped

Comment: If decimal parts is all zero , u still want to show ? @Kex

Comment: Yes. I solved it in the end by checking if amountString has . in it and no trailing digits. If it does then I just append "." to `Text`

Comment: Thats why I asked that :) .I'm glad you solved the problem